# How to split a datetime string into 2 pieces

Tags: javascript

I have a datetime string coming back as

> "2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM"

I know I can split it by using the split(" ") method, but it gives me 3 seperate pieces

2018-02-22, 3:42:49, PM

but I need it as
2018-02-22, 3:42:49 PM

I can probably just concantenate the last 2 but that would probably be dirty

Comment: Find index of first space, take substring before and after. Or if you can guarantee that the date is YYYY-MM-DD followed by space then you know the location of the space. Or parse it into a datetime object and use that for whatever you need.

Comment: You can simply use `s.substring(0, 10)` and `s.substring(11)`, where `s` contains the datetime string. This works because the length of the date part is always the same.

Comment: @kol, thats eaxctly what I did

Comment: @jarmod, do you have an example of what you are speaking of about parsing it becaus I just tried Date.parse and that didnt work

Comment: What didn't work with `Date.parse()`? It returns ms since Jan 1, 1970. You can use it to create a Date object, for example: `dt = new Date(Date.parse("2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM"))`.

Comment: @jarmod It's easier to just `new Date("2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM")`, the `Date` constructor calls `Date.parse` implicitly. Also, a word of warning: `Date.parse` has long been implementation dependent, and it may still return different values in different browsers in some edge-cases...

Comment: @jarmod, for my it returned 1519332169000, one sec... i did it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```js
//your date string
var dt = "2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM";

//slice date by index
var d = dt.slice(0,10);


//slice time by index 
var t = dt.slice(11,21);
//check if hour is double digits by checking length of dt string
if (dt.length > 21) {
t = dt.slice(11,22)
}

//add date and time with space inbetween
var dplust = d + ' ' + t;

//get p ids for example
var justDate = document.getElementById("justDate");
var justTime = document.getElementById("justTime");
var dplustDiv = document.getElementById("dplust");

//set inner html of p for examples
justDate.innerHTML = 'This is just date - ' + d;

justTime.innerHTML = 'This is just time - ' + t;

dplustDiv.innerHTML = 'This is date plus time - ' + dplust;

console.log(d);
console.log(t);
```

```html
<p id="justDate"></p>

<p id="justTime"></p>

<p id="dplust"></p>
```

Comment: What if the hour is two-digit? It can break this code!

Comment: See updated snippet. - It checks for string length in case hour is two-digit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex and [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) then you get only 2 pieces

```js
let dateString = "2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM";
let dateParts = dateString.match(/^(\S+)\s(.*)/).slice(1); // slice(1) removes the first match as that is the full string which is not needed
console.log('1: ', dateParts[0] + ', ' + dateParts[1]);
// or because it's only two parts you can also use join
console.log('2: ', dateParts.join(', '));

console.log('Array length: ' + dateParts.length, dateParts);
```

The reason for why using `.match()` over `.split()` in this case is because with `.match()` you can use a lookbehind. Apparently that's not supported with `.split()` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you, since thinking about it, instead of doing an array,

Maybe you just identify the space with a index and then take what you want from the string like this:

```
    var DT = "2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM";
    var SplitDateTime = DT.indexOf(" ");
    var eDate = DT.substring(0, SplitDateTime); // 2018-02-22
    var eTime = DT.substring(SplitDateTime + 1); // 3:42:49 PM
```

have a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

that ?

```js
function transfDate(sDate)
  {
  let [yyyy,mm,dd,h,m,s,t] = sDate.match(/\d{1,4}|AM|PM/g)

  return [`${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`, `${h}:${m}:${s} ${t}`]
  }

console.log( transfDate( '2018-02-22 3:42:49 PM')  )
              // return -> [ "2018-02-22", "3:42:49 PM" ]
```